How to decode the output of Yolov8 detection predictions?
I have a Yolov8-n detection model that simply detects two classes with bounding boxes and confidences: cat and dog. When I visualize the model with Netron (HERE), the last array shows as 1x6x10710 as shown below. The raw prediction numpy array from the model is saved as a .bin file that I read:
array = np.fromfile(yolo_data_path)
The size of the .bin file is exacly 257,040. Since the output is float32 [1,6,10710], so the output size seems to be correct: 4x6x10710 = 257,040
Now given that I have this .bin output array, how can I read it and decode the bbox and print the final detections? Basically, the bounding boxes, class and their confidences. I assume that 6 is basically 4 bounding boxes, confidence and class number.
Looking at the Yolov8 predict.py, I understand somehow after parsing these preditions, we have to pass them through non_max_suppression() to get the final results.

You need to iterate over the 10710 anchors and keep the rows above the threshold. See this for an example.

So just doing that iteration and then applying NMS to get the final results? That's it?

Yes that should be it. Take the cat/dog image you have and try to draw the boxes on it to see if the results look okay.

@Mercury The example works. But how can I replace cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes with the non_max_suppression() function in Yolov8 predict.py? https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/blob/main/ultralytics/models/yolo/detect/predict.py
